# Checking the umask in shell script

Tags: bash, sh, umask

How do I check if the umask prevents the group bits from being set? My attempt:

```
#!/bin/sh

out=$(umask)
echo "$out"

if (($out & 070) != 0); then
    echo "$out"
    echo "Incorrect umask" > /dev/tty
    exit 1
fi
```

Output:

```
./test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `!='
./test.sh: line 6: `if (($out & 070) != 0); then'
```

I'm ok with switching to bash if it makes things easier.

Comment: Your question is getting close votes because it is "too broad". Instead of asking for us to write the entire solution, you should do your best to code it yourself and, if you can't get it working, then post what you have written here and ask for help to fix it.

Comment: My attempt so far is a disaster. I have added it with the question.

Comment: Thank you. I think you need `if [ $umask & 070 -ne 0 ]` or just `if [ $umask & 070 ]`. It's not hard to find with a quick google.

Comment: `./test.sh: line 6: [: missing ]
./test.sh: line 6: 070: command not found`
 was what I got when I tried that earlier

Comment: You're missing a space somewhere. You need to copy what I wrote.

Comment: I don't think so. 
Here's a fiddle http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMV2tPMzJ4NVRmUlU

Comment: You are using the wrong shebang; should be `/bin/bash` (or something with `bash`), not `/bin/sh`.

Comment: `0970:dir> ls -lrt /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Oct 15  2016 /bin/sh -> bash`
How about now?

Comment: Thank you for adding code ("disaster" or not :).  I've removed my close vote.

Comment: @Jean, When `bash` is invoked as using `sh`, it tries to emulate `sh`.

Comment: @Boridin, `if [ $umask & ...` means run `if [ $umask` in the background, then execute `...` as a separate command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use double parentheses to get an arithmetic evaluation.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

```
m=$(umask)
if (( ($m & 070) != 0 )); then 
    echo error
fi
```

Or you could treat the umask as a string and use [glob-pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
if [[ $m == *0? ]]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo err
fi
```

bash has lots of unique syntax: it's not C/perl-like at all. Read (or at least refer to) the manual and read lots of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) questions here. Keep asking questions.

Comment: Answer I was looking for. Especially the last part. Thanks!

Comment: I meant to actually link to the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html